# Is it possible to move single open file between panes in VS Code?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

I want to have the openned in VSCode file moved from one pane to another. Just like in Sublime `ctrl+shift+1` / `ctrl+shift+2`. What command is in charge of this?

1. split editor vertically (the second pane is empty), I do this by `workbench.action.editoLayoutTwoColumns`
2. move current open file from the first pane to the second

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and search for `View: Move Editor into` to bring up related commands. In this case, you might be specifically looking for the following:

**Command**

`Move Editor into Next Group`

**Shortcuts**

- Mac: <kbd>ctrl+cmd+right</kbd>
- Windows/Linux: <kbd>ctrl+alt+right</kbd>).